# How to put MySQL results in Bootstrap items

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli, pagination, division

I want to fetch results of a MySQL database and put them into "pages" in my webpages.

What I have is a bootstrap webpage and I'm using items to show the posts but I want to show let's say 5 entries per item and instead of making pages I want to sort them into items to show the entries.

Is this possible and how is it possible?

What I have now and does work is the following code:

```
<div class="item">
   div class="testimony-slide active text-center">

<?php

   $sql = "SELECT name,email,message FROM guestbook ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   echo "<figure>";
   echo "<img src=\"../images/guestbook.png\">";
   echo "</figure>";
   echo !empty($row['name']) ? ("<span>". $row['name'] . "</span>") : '';
   echo !empty($row['email']) ? ("<span>". $row['email'] . "</span>") : '';
   echo "<blockquote>";
   echo !empty($row['message']) ? ("<p>". $row['message'] . "</p>") : '';
   echo "</blockquote>";
   }

   mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
   div class="testimony-slide active text-center">

<?php

   $sql = "SELECT name,email,message FROM guestbook ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   echo "<figure>";
   echo "<img src=\"../images/guestbook.png\">";
   echo "</figure>";
   echo !empty($row['name']) ? ("<span>". $row['name'] . "</span>") : '';
   echo !empty($row['email']) ? ("<span>". $row['email'] . "</span>") : '';
   echo "<blockquote>";
   echo !empty($row['message']) ? ("<p>". $row['message'] . "</p>") : '';
   echo "</blockquote>";
   }

   mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this code is that it makes me do it manually, so that makes it a pain in the ass... I want it to be split into items according to the entries found in the database.

I tried solutions i found on google, but they all are made for seperate pages and not making the results split inside divs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable to keep track of how many rows are printed, and segregate the rows into different *div*s accordingly. So your code should be like this:

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="testimony-slide active text-center">
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT name,email,message FROM guestbook ORDER BY ID DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysqli_error($conn));
        $counter = 1;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo "<figure>";
           echo "<img src=\"../images/guestbook.png\">";
           echo "</figure>";
           echo !empty($row['name']) ? ("<span>". $row['name'] . "</span>") : '';
           echo !empty($row['email']) ? ("<span>". $row['email'] . "</span>") : '';
           echo "<blockquote>";
           echo !empty($row['message']) ? ("<p>". $row['message'] . "</p>") : '';
           echo "</blockquote>";

           if($counter % 5 == 0){
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="item"><div class="testimony-slide active text-center">';
           }
           ++$counter;
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't mix `mysql` and `mysqli` APIs, those are two different things. `mysql_error()` should be `mysqli_error($conn)`.

Comment: Thanks!!!! works like a charm! and thanks for noticing the mysql_error that i forgot to change to mysqli after changing everything in the script to mysqli

Comment: still one question... i just deleted the test messages and the page refuses to load because it had not enough messages to seperate "pages". How can I fix that?

Comment: @FGOD What do you mean by *page refuses to load*? Is it throwing some error?

Comment: no it it stuck on the loading page icon that keeps spinning as though it tries to determine if it needs more pages then one but can't without giving me php error output... strange thing is that it has the same problem with with my index page where i output only the last 3 messages with 1 message per item div. As soon as I have 3 messages it loads the page like normal but with less then 3 it gets stuck on the loading icon. Same goes for the guestbook page which needs 5 as that is the limit for the first item div. with less then 5 it just gets stuck on the loading icon.

Comment: @FGOD Then it's a very specific bootstrap related issue, and not related to the question you asked above. I'd suggest you to create a separate question on SO explaining all the details i.e. plugins, js code etc.